# The for loop goes beyond set up condition

Tags: java, for-loop

I've set up for loop to make "i" to be incremented until "i < 10". After the for was finished I added an output statement after closing curly parentheses to show i value and it resulted to 10, whereas I thought that the max value could have been only 9.
Could someone please explain what does cause "i" to go beyond it's maximum value of 9?

Many thanks,
Vlad

```
public class Recap3 {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
         System.out.println(i); // this statement lists values from 0 to 9
     } System.out.println(i); // this statement returns i = 10
   }
 }
```

Comment: If `i` would only go up to 9, `i<10` would never be false.

Comment: The question seems a bit artificial because this is not the idiomatic/normal way to use the `for` loop. The normal way is to declare and initialize the _loop control variable_ (`i`) within the loop (`for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)`). This way, `i` is only scoped within the loop and you wouldn't need to wonder what its value is after the loop (because it would not exist there).

Comment: thanks Mick! will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

After each iteration of the loop, Java will execute the third term of the `for` loop, `i++`. Then, it checks if `i<10`. If this results in `true`, it continues the for loop, otherwise it stops.

This means that first, java sets i equal to 10, then checks if it is less than 10, and then breaks.

The statements executed look something like this:

```
System.out.println(i); //i=9
i++; //i=10
if(!(i<10)) break;//This breaks out of the loop
System.out.println(i); //i=10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. `i` being incremented to 10 is the expected behavior.

After each iteration the following steps occur:

1. Perform the the 3rd statement in the for loop
2. Then evaluate the conditional expression in the second portion.
3. If the conditional expression evaluates to true, execute the loop body and go back to the the first step. If the conditional expression evaluate to false, continue execution after the loop.

So on the iteration when `i` is equal to `9`, `i` is first incremented to `10`, then compared: `i<10`. Since `i<10` is false, the loop terminates. At that point, `i` is equal to `10`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is checked before the body of the loop and it is incremented after the body.

In the last few iterations of the loop (starting at `i = 9`), the following happens:

1. The condition `i<10` is checked. 9 is less than 10 so the loop continues.
2. The body of the loop is run and the value 9 is printed to the screen.
3. The variable `i` is incremented, giving it the value 10.
4. The condition `i<10` is checked. 10 is not less than 10 so the loop exits.
5. The statement outside the loop is run. The value of `i` is 10 so 10 is printed to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The second System.out.println is outside of the loop. The loop does only go up to 9. You can use if else statements to create a highnumber and then have the System.out.println(highnumber) on the outside of the loop.